# How to fix OS X select html tag behavior?

Tags: html, css, macos, select, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to customize select with css and javascript, with opacity and additional tag, but I've got next issue in OS X webkit browsers:
[image: OS X dropdown]
How can I avoid this? In other systems all the browers (i.e. webkit) looks good.

Comment: What's the issue? It's hard to tell what you consider to be an issue from that image.

Comment: There is no standard way to fix. Maybe you can use jQuery UI, or other JavaScript solution, with fake selects

Comment: sorry, issue is that dropdown options is over the dropdown, not below.

Comment: There's no way to control this with pure css. The placement of the options is browser/OS specific.
You said you're using js; do you use a specific plugin? There are some pluings (for example: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html ) that can control this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style real dropdowns…

but you can use this 'menu style' things if you edit a bit…

http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/475667